# App in space or in different space

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I know that every application the deploy to CF space are deployed to isolated container .
application in space can share service instance which is not the case for application in
different spaces ...
my question is that: I know that the application from different spaces doesn't have
any way to impact other application 
but in case of two applications are deployed to the same space, there is a way that it
have "privileges " to harm (from security perspective...) other application in
the space 
which is not available to applications that deployed to different spaces ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, whether two apps are pushed to the same or different spaces does not make a difference in that respect.
The reason they cannot share a service instance unless they're part of the same space is an organizational restriction (to e.g. prevent you from accidentally binding your production database service to your dev space's apps) and is not enforced on the network level.
(Which you can confirm by copying the service instance's credentials and create a user-provided service instance in the other space and bind that to the other app: both can access the target service fine. <- this is a work-around to address certain use cases, like a message queue shared by apps in different spaces, to which we are currently exploring a proper solution for).

Comment: Ok Thanks 1+, what about network/cpu , there is a way that one application that is CPU intensive will harm other application in space ? or even in different space ?

Comment: You can configure isolation segments to have apps of certain spaces placed on isolated hardware to prevent such harm. Without isolation segments, apps could be placed on the same or different VMs (regardless of whether they're in the same space or different), which although guaranteed to each get their fair share, some contention for resources may remain.

Comment: Thanks , so just to verify . if I dont use isolation segment one app that are high CPU intensive can cause to other app in space/org to be un-responsive during load time. am I right ?